# Saving recorded audio as .wav via openAL

Tags: c++, audio, openal

I am trying to record audio using C++ with openAL and save it as .wav file, so far i suceeded with first part, but can't find a way to save audio in a file. I read documentation and didn't find any way to do so. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

To save a *.wav file, you don't really need OpenAL. Look at the *.wav type-specifications, which are all over the web. You have just to create a header which describes your data and paste in your recorded data.